# &trade; from database not showing symbol

Tags: php, html, sql, database, symbols

In my database, some products have a ™ symbol next to them. This is recorded in the database by `&trade;`. However when I echo this out from the database, it literally prints out `&trade;` instead of the actual ™ symbol.

Any ideas on how I can avoid this and get it to actually display the symbol?

Comment: can you show us how are you printing it out?

Comment: `echo $row['title'];`

Comment: How do you retrieve the records from the database? Do you use any orm or dbal? Do you use any php framework?

Comment: If you do it like that and if database contains `&trade;` then if you are using a web browser to display it then it should show up as `TM` . there is a lot of ifs. check if you have not double encoded the string and stored as `&amp;trade;`

Comment: what value print in `echo $row['title']`

Comment: What doctype are you using?  &trade; isn't in the XHTML entities so will only work with HTML.  Also, are you escaping the characters (e.g., using `htmlentities()`) from the database before you send the output?  You may be double-encoding the ampersand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this can work for you try replacing &trade with the code mentioned by @wild.

```
$string = "&trade; here is a string";
$search = "&trade;";
$replace =  '&#0153';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

use  this code where you want to print TM

```
echo '&#0153';
```

Comment: use it where u want to print TM

Comment: Don't forget the semi-colon: `echo '&#0153;';`